# Imacros: how to find TAG position of a submit button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, imacros

My html page code looks like below with zero to multiple buttons shown below

```
<input type="submit" value="Amend" onclick="jQuery('#adjust_item_id').val(1234); setAction(this.form, 'adjust',0,null, 1);">
```

The html can have multiple buttons as above and fixed buttons as below.

Addition to above button/s, there are more fixed buttons on the page shown below.

Depending on how many buttons shows up on the page the POS of the below buttons also change

```
<div class="xyz-buttons">

    <input value="Back" type="submit" onclick="setAction(this.form, 'back','0',null, '0');">
    <input value="Clone" type="submit" onclick="setAction(this.form, 'clone','0',null, '1');">
    
    <input value="FINISH" type="submit" onclick="setAction(this.form, 'save_validate','0',null, '1');" class="GreenButton">
```

I am trying to find the POS of the button "Clone" to repeat a task.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:pfbc-buttons

TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:FCLS7022 ATTR=ID:clone
```

I tried number of ways to find the POS of "Clone" button but to no avail.

Could someone please point me to the right direction to find the POS to simulate a click on the page please.

Comment: Would be "easier" if you could post the URL, or at least a Screenshot of the Page, difficult to grasp the HTML Structure of the Page "blindly"... // 'Relative Positioning' like you tried with `POS=R1` could be the/a way indeed, (but you'd need to use '*Double* R-POS' to use that 'pfbc-buttons' `DIV` as Anchor, as it is a *Containing* `DIV`), and `ATTR=ID:clone` doesn't look correct to me, those `INPUT` Elements don't seem to have an `ID`... // You can google "Double Relative Positioning", I've explained and demonstrated the Concept many times on the iMacros Forum... :idea:

Comment: The [tag:google-chrome] and [tag:firefox] Tags add no Value to your Qt btw, you could better read the [iMacros Tag Wiki](/tags/imacros/info) and mention your FCI(s)...

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Used TAG but recorded the xpath with turning CSS style from imacros settings.